# Yahoo Search opens when I open a new tab in Firefox

Tags: firefox

One of my latest new Plug-Ins probably caused this issue. As the title says, every time, when I open a new tab in Firefox, de.search.yahoo.com opens. This is really annoying, I wonder how a professional enterprise like Yahoo can act this way. How can I get rid of that?

Not successful:

- I tried to remove Yahoo from the searchengines in the search bar
- I looked in my Plug-Ins, but didn't find anything obviously relating to Yahoo
- Restarting Firefox doesn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your new tab page has been altered by some add-on that was probably bundled with some unwanted software.

If you've removed that add-on already, you can get the initial new tab page back by going to about:config - I'll be careful - browser.newtab.url - right click - reset

You'll notice that the value changes from *.yahoo.com to about:newtab

Ctrl+T to verify

You can use the same configuration to set your own new tab URL too.

Comment: Also needed to search for Yahoo in that about:config window and disable a couple more things to stop it coming back

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Chrome. Go to your top right browser bar and scroll to extensions. Click on it. I found the Yahoo extension at the bottom of the list. I unchecked it then deleted it. Problem solved. So annoying.